# conversion of cell to matrix that contains text?

Tags: matlab, matrix, text-processing, cell-array, textscan

I have the text file that contains measurement data, the header is not that important so I used this to remove the first 25 lines

```
% Skip the first 25 lines
for i=1:25
fgetl(inputfile);
end
```

Then I used delimiter in order to get the data

```
   delimiter = '';
   values = textscan(inputfile, '%s', 'delimiter', delimiter);
```

I am trying to convert cell that consists of 1000 char as in the following.
Here what I got

```
'2014_11_03_17-19-49 000 430114 516672 960.91 26.2'
'2014_11_03_17-19-49 001 430112 516656 960.91 26.2'
'2014_11_03_17-19-49 002 430112 516656 960.91 26.2'
'2014_11_03_17-19-49 003 430112 516656 960.91 26.2'
```

I am trying to convert cell that consists of 1000 char as in the previous I am concerning about (960.91 and 26.2) values only.

I tried to convert it to matrix but i got

> this error Cannot support cell arrays containing cell arrays or objects.

Any idea how to just got those values into matrix to plot them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

You can use the nifty **[`importdata`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html)** here -

```
lines_skip = 25;
values = importdata(inputfile,' ',lines_skip) %// using the delimiter ' ' here
```

`values` would be a struct holding the data from `inputfile`.

Thus, `fourth column` would  be `values.data(:,4)`, while `values.data(:,5)` would be the `fifth` one as shown here -

```
>> values.data(:,4)
ans =
  960.9100
  960.9100
  960.9100
  960.9100
>> values.data(:,5)
ans =
   26.2000
   26.2000
   26.2000
   26.2000
```

---

**Approach #2**

If you already have the cell array as listed in the question, you don't need to worry about reading the input file again. So, you have something like this -

```
incell = {
    '2014_11_03_17-19-49 000 430114 516672 960.91 26.2'
    '2014_11_03_17-19-49 001 430112 516656 960.91 26.2'
    '2014_11_03_17-19-49 002 430112 516656 960.91 26.2'
    '2014_11_03_17-19-49 003 430112 516656 960.91 26.2'}
```

Next, you can use `cellfun` with `regexp` to split each cell into columns using the delimiter `' '` -

```
cellarr = cellfun(@(x) regexp(x,' ','Split'),incell,'un',0)
values = vertcat(cellarr{:})
```

which will get you -

```
values = 
    '2014_11_03_17-19-49'    '000'    '430114'    '516672'    '960.91'    '26.2'
    '2014_11_03_17-19-49'    '001'    '430112'    '516656'    '960.91'    '26.2'
    '2014_11_03_17-19-49'    '002'    '430112'    '516656'    '960.91'    '26.2'
    '2014_11_03_17-19-49'    '003'    '430112'    '516656'    '960.91'    '26.2'
```

That is, fifth and sixth columns from `values` would be the data you were looking to have after wrapping `str2double` around them : `str2double(values(:,5))` and `str2double(values(:,6))`.

Comment: in case of these  data in this format  `'2014_11_03_17-19-49' '000' '430114' '516672' '960.91' '26.2' '2014_11_03_17-19-49' '001' '430112' '516656' '960.91' '26.2' '2014_11_03_17-19-49' '002' '430112' '516656' '960.91' '26.2'` and text for 2 line then `'2014_11_03_17-19-49' '000' '430114' '516672' '960.91' '26.2' '2014_11_03_17-19-49' '001' '430112' '516656' '960.91' '26.2' '2014_11_03_17-19-49' '002' '430112' '516656' '960.91' '26.2'`

Comment: how can i bypass these 2 line and get the data ?

Comment: @mecaeng Let's suppose `a1` is your `line 1`, so you have - `a1 = {'2014_11_03_17-19-49' '000' '430114' '516672' '960.91' '26.2' '2014_11_03_17-19-49' '001' '430112' '516656' '960.91' '26.2' '2014_11_03_17-19-49' '002' '430112' '516656' '960.91' '26.2'}`. Then do `data_a1 = reshape(a1,6,[])'`. Thus, in `data_a1` you would have many columns, out of which you need the fifth and sixth columns. So, then do `col5 = data_a1(:,5)` and finally get the numeric values with `col5_num = str2double(col5)`. See if this works.

Comment: Let me be more clear :  suppose that is my file :  first 25 lines (just headers-not important )  then number of line as this format **'2014_11_03_17-19-49' '000' '430114' '516672' '960.91' '26.2'** then another 2 lines (headers-not important) and again the measured data **2014_11_03_17-19-49' '000' '430114' '516672' '960.91' '26.2**

Comment: by your approach that successfully obtained that date for for the first part .. the point here how to pass the new headers and get the data ... I have like 1000 headers in one file

Comment: @mecaeng How do we differentiate between headers and the numbered data? Like do the header text start with some letters like A or B or just anything, but not a digit?

Comment: Nope. they start with the same (date) but headers are equally repeated .like 100 lines of data then 2 (line)headers then again the 100 lines of data and so on

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64326/discussion-on-answer-by-divakar-conversion-of-cell-to-matrix-that-contains-text).

Answer (score 1):

Use a different format specifier with [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) the [`'HeaderLines'` option](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#inputarg_HeaderLines) to skip the header directly:

```
>> fid = fopen('testtext.txt','r','HeaderLines',25)
>> C = textscan(fid,'%s %d %d %d %f %f')
C = 
    {4x1 cell}   [4x1 int32]   [4x1 int32]   [4x1 int32]   [4x1 double]   [4x1 double]
>> fclose(fid);
>> C{5}

  960.9100
  960.9100
  960.9100
  960.9100
```

Make a matrix by concatentation, if you want it like so:

```
>> M =[C{5} C{6}]
M =

  960.9100   26.2000
  960.9100   26.2000
  960.9100   26.2000
  960.9100   26.2000
```

You can even specify to ignore all but the outputs you want:

```
C = textscan(fid,'%*s %*d %*d %*d %f %*f')
C = 
    [4x1 double]
```

Don't forget to `fclose(fid)` or `fclose all` if you lost the handle.

Comment: I am using .log file  and I got that error  Invalid machine format.

Comment: @mecaeng What command gave that, and what was the exact wording?